# Show if M is a positive local martingale with $E(M_0)<\infty$ then $M$ is a supermartingale.

Tags: limits, probability-theory, martingales

A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807579/bounded-from-below-continuous-local-martingale-is-a-supermartingale) but I have a question about one of the steps.

To show that $M_t \in M := \{M_t : t \in [0,\infty)$ is integrable we consider $M_{t \wedge T_n}$ where $\{T_n\}$ are stopping times almost surey increasing to $\infty$. Then $M_{t \wedge T_n} \to M_t$ almost surely. We can now apply Fatou's Lemma to get that  $$E(M_t) \le \liminf\limits _{n \to \infty}E(M_{t \wedge T_n}) = E(M_0)$$

But why does $\liminf\limits _{n \to \infty}E(M_{t \wedge T_n}) = E(M_0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_{t\wedge T_n}: t \geq 0$ is a martingale for each $n$. So $EM_{t\wedge T_n}=EM_{0\wedge T_n}=EM_0$.

Comment: Maybe there is a property of martingales that I am not familiar with but why does $M_{t\wedge T_n}$ being a martingale for $t \ge 0$ and for every $n$  imply that  $EM_{t\wedge T_n}=EM_{0\wedge T_n}$?

Comment: @alpastor If $\{X_t\}$ is a martingale then $EX_t$ is in dependent of $t$. To see this just take expectation in the definition of martingale.

Comment: You mean independent right? $$ E(X_s)=E\left[E(X_s)\right]=E\left[E(X_t|\mathcal F_s)\right] = E(X_t)$$. Thank you, for the explanation

Comment: @alpastor Yes. I just left a gap after 'in' in 'independent'. A typo.

Comment: oh didnt see the in was there, anyways thank you!